# List vs Dictionary when referring by index/key

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

So I have been mainly using lists to retrieve small amounts of data from a database which feeds into a web application but have recently come across dictionaries which produce more readable code with keys but what is the performance difference when just referring by index/key?

I understand that a dictionary uses more memory but what is best practice in this scenario and is it worth the performance/maintenance trade-off bearing in mind that I will not be performing searches or sorting the data?

Comment: Do you need to search an element of your data using a key?

Comment: Why is performance an issue for you?

Comment: @Steve ideally I want to refer to it by a meaningful value e.g. assetrecord["assetid"] rather than assetrecord[0] but is this the general practice in my scenario? It is only one record so I am not searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do want to find some one item through list, then you should see ALL items till you find its key.
Let's see some basic example. You have

```
Person
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and you have collection `List<Person> persons` and you want to find some person by its `ID`:

```
var person = persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 5);
```

As written it has to enumerate the entire List until it finds the entry in the List that has the correct `ID` (does entry 0 match the lambda? No... Does entry 1 match the lambda? No... etc etc). `This is O(n)`.

However, if you want to find through the Dictionary dictPersons :

```
var person = dictPersons[person.ID];
```

If you want to find a certain element by key in a dictionary, it can instantly jump to where it is in the dictionary - **this is O(1)**. O(n) for doing it for every person. (If you want to know how this is done - Dictionary runs a mathematical operation on the key, which turns it into a value that is a place inside the dictionary, which is the same place it put it when it was inserted. It is called hash-function)

So, `Dictionary` is faster than `List`because Dictionary does not iterate through the all collection, but Dictionary takes the item from the exact place(hash-function calculates this place). It is a better algorithm.

`Dictionary` relies on chaining (maintaining a list of items for each hash table bucket) to resolve collisions whereas `Hashtable` uses rehashing for collision resolution (when a collision occurs, tries another hash function to map the key to a bucket). [You can read how hash function works and difference between chaining and rehashing.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Comment: He did not ask 'find' but index/key access.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're actually experiencing performance issues and need to optimize it's better to go with what's more readable and maintainable. That's especially true since you mentioned that it's small amounts of data. Without exaggerating - it's possible that over the life of the application the cumulative difference in performance (if any) won't equal the time you save by making your code more readable.

To put it in perspective, consider the work that your application already does just to read request headers and parse views and read values from configuration files. Not only will the difference in performance between the list and the dictionary be small, it will also be a tiny fraction of the overall processing your application does just to serve a single page request.

And even then, if you were to see performance issues and needed to optimize, there would probably be plenty of other optimizations (like caching) that would make a bigger difference.